# Proxy service for REST calls

Tags: asp.net, rest, proxy

I've got a small ASP.NET web site, that calls another company (somewhat) Restful web service. My site has no logging currently. Is there an online service that can proxy all calls from my site and provide error logging and possibly retry functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried https://ngrok.com/ - For local development, it's probably exactly what you're looking for.

If you just want to inspect the traffic your system is sending out or receiving, http://www.telerik.com/fiddler is a good choice.